# Chrome crashes with too many web components

Tags: google-chrome, web, firefox, components

I have an HTML table with at most 25 columns (usually 5 or 6) and at most 25 rows. Each cell in the table contains a custom Web Component. These are minimal web components. For example, one wraps a number and you can set number formatting (e.g. format as currency) via the attributes. Another just displays a formatted string, etc. I am adding these components dynamically using appendChild on the td.

These Web Components are all using the Shadow DOM - as recommended in the documentation. So I create this simple table (6 rows and 25 columns) and I populate cells with these Web Components. If I do this in Chrome, my system crashes requiring a reboot (sometimes by forcing a shutdown). I tried this in Firefox, and the table renders in less than a second. Also I tried this in Edge and it crashes there too.

I tried re-doing my Web Components to remove the Shadow DOMs and *voila*, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I don't want to do these component without the Shadow DOMs. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you can reliably crash the browser, I'd report the bug: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug/  Crash bugs can sometimes be exploited as security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for responding... II will try your suggestion and report the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is still a problem. I tested in Edge browser and it does indeed work there (albeit a bit slow). Also tested in Safari/ MacOS and it works there too.

What a shame… I have to tell my users they can’t use Chrome and prevent the page from loading.

Update 9/2/2022: Without any changes to my code it is no longer an issue. The only explanation I have is that it might have been happily addressed by a scheduled Chrome update.

Now however, even though my table loads OK, if I open Developer Tools immediately after the table loads, I get a crash with error: '**Debugging Connection closed. Reason: Render process gone.**'

Update 9/4/2022: I was overly optimistic about this error. I started testing my app again in Chrome today and the original problem still exists. I create my table in Chrome, interact with it in various ways (e.g. dynamically add a column, add an icon prefix to cell contents of a column, dynamically add a column with a drop-down menu in each cell, etc.) and eventually Chrome will crash.

I no longer expect this to be fixed. I logged a bug report with chromium.org and that is all I can do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).